# Using jQuery, how do I target a child element in a parent object's hover state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a bunch of list items, like so:

```
 <li>
     <a href="#" style="background:url('someImage.jpg')">
        <span class="wInfo">Hello World</span>
     </a>
 </li>
```

The anchor tag is actually a display:block element in CSS. The span class is a bit of text floating on top of an image. The text has a background-color of #000000. Now, using jQuery, I want to make a hover action for the anchor link, which changes wInfo's background-color to #ff0000.

My code isn't working, any ideas?

```
$('#work li a').hover(
   function(){
       $(this.find('.wInfo')).css({backgroundColor:'white'});
    },
    function(){
       $(this.find('.wInfo')).css({backgroundColor:'black'});
    }
);
```

Comment: `this` refers to a DOM element, not a jQuery object. `find` is a jQuery method.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the most likely problem is a simple typo, it should be:

```
$('#work li a').hover(
   function(){
       $(this).find('.wInfo').css({backgroundColor:'white'});
    },
    function(){
       $(this).find('.wInfo').css({backgroundColor:'black'});
    }
);
```

Note the added closing parenthesis after `this`.

Comment: Thanks, @Felix; for some reason I didn't see the double-parenthesis... *sigh* =)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do it in css?

```
#work li a:hover .winfo {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Cufon on the span class, and I'm actually also trying to change the text color as well. I just didn't mention that here to keep my example simple.

Comment: Understood, I should have guessed.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you're referencing the object incorrectly.  `$(this)` will reference the current object that you are working with.  In your code, your selector is `$(this.find('.wInfo'))`, which is incorrect as you need to close the parentheses after `this`.

Try:

```
$(#work 'li a').hover(
   function(){
       $(this).find('.wInfo').css({backgroundColor:'white'});
    },
    function(){
       $(this).find('.wInfo').css({backgroundColor:'black'});
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling your event handler function(s) jQuery will set `this` to the actual element.

So try changing:

```
$(this.find('.wInfo')).css({backgroundColor:'white'});
```

to

```
$(this).find('.wInfo').css({backgroundColor:'white'});
```

When you say `$(this)` it will give you a jQuery object that you can use `.find()` on.